Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'id') error when calling Content.js from Background.js using context menu
I seem to be having trouble defining the tab on which to run the script of a chrome extension. It may be related to starting the extension from the context menu (right click) but not matter how I reference the current tab,all tabs, any tab, I always get an error relating to referencing the tab.
I have tried a number of ways of referencing the current tab and calling the ID of the current tab. I believe it is because I am starting the operation from the context tab. I am expecting to right click on the browser window, view the context menu, select the 'capture' option and then start the script.
here is my manifest.js
`{
  "manifest_version": 3,
  "name": "Capture Extension",
  "version": "1.0",
  "description": "Adds 'Capture' option to the context menu",
  "permissions": ["contextMenus",  "scripting", "activeTab"] ,
  "background": {
    "service_worker": "background.js"
  },
   "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
      "js": ["content.js"]
    }
  ],
  "icons": {
    "16": "icon16.png"

  }
}`

background.js
`chrome.contextMenus.create({
  id: "captureContextMenu",
  title: "Capture",
  contexts: ["all"]
});


chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(msg, sender, sendResponse) {
  if (msg.text == "what is my tab_id?") {
      sendResponse({tab: sender.tab.id});
   }
});


console.log("test1")

chrome.contextMenus.onClicked.addListener(function(info, tab) {

  console.log("test2")
  if (info.menuItemId === "captureContextMenu" /*&& info.button === 0*/) {

    console.log("test3")

/* need to update 'chrome.tabs.executeScript' command to run in the background of chrome and call a script
Maybe define the tab

*/
    chrome.scripting.executeScript(
     {tab: tab[0].id, allFrames : true},
      { file: 'Content.js' }, function() {
     
      console.log("test5")

      if (chrome.runtime.lastError) {
        console.error(chrome.runtime.lastError.message);
      } else {
        chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tab.id, { action: "greyOut" });
      }
    });
  }
});`


content.js
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(message, sender, sendResponse) {
console.log('testing 7')

Remove [0] so it's just tab.id, see the documentation for onClicked parameters.
